# Show that $T^3=O$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let V be a vector space over field F with a basis $\{\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3\}$ and T is linear mapping on V such that $T(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$, $T(\alpha_2)=\alpha_3$, $T(\alpha_3)=0$. Show that $T^3=O$ (O=zero mapping).

Attempt

$T^3(\alpha_i)=\cdots=0$ for all $i=1,2,3$. Does it mean $T^3=O$. If yes, please elaborate.

Edit
 $\theta=0$, replaced.

Comment: I suggest to change the notation $\theta$ for the zero vector: this is unusual and misleading

Comment: It follows immediately from the definition of linearity that a linear map $T$ is characterized by its values $T(E_1), \ldots, T(E_n)$ at the elements of (any) basis $(E_a)$.

Comment: Yes, it means that, since a *linear mapping* is completely determined by its valus on **any** basis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$T(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2 \Rightarrow T^2(\alpha_1)=T(\alpha_2)=\alpha_3 \Rightarrow T^3(\alpha_1)=T(\alpha_3)=0$$
and the last result works also for $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$. So $T^3(\alpha_1)=T^3(\alpha_2)=T^3(\alpha_3)=0$.

If we take any $u \in V$ then $u=u_1 \alpha_1+u_2 \alpha_2+u_3 \alpha_3$ and:

$$T^3(u)=u_1 T^3(\alpha_1)+u_2 T^3(\alpha_2)+u_3 T^3(\alpha_3)=0$$

so $T^3=0$

Answer (score 0):

You can either see that for a basis of $V$ the operator is null, or just take the matrix with respect to the basis you got, and verify that the matrix to the third power equals zero.

Comment: Edited $\theta$

Comment: Fixed to match the edited question. Thanks.